# 3 incrementing buttons, optimal value

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

This was asked on PhysicsForums.com and I am very interested in seeing a nice solution.

Suppose we want a user to be able to enter any numeric value from 1 to 100. This number is entered by 3 buttons, each assigned a value; these buttons increment the value from 0. For example, if the user was to enter "52" and the value of the 3 buttons was (1,5,20), then the user would press 20, 20, 5, 5, 1, 1.

Since all numbers from 1 to 100 must be able to be entered, one of the buttons must be assigned "1," clearly.

The question is, what numeric value for the other two buttons will provide the least number of clicks for a value, on average?

Or equivalently, what assignment of buttons will require the least number of clicks to enter all numbers from 1 to 100 (incrementing from 0 each time, of course)?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: seems a fairly easy computer program to try every triple (there is no reason to have a key above 100) and, for each triple, find (A) the average from 1 to 100 of clicks required, (B) the worst case from 1 to 100. The program uses bounds, no more than C clicks, say C = 25 to start, for a fixed triple, every time a number n can be expressed in fewer clicks the new optimum is saved in array clicks[n].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was curious, I wrote a little python-script to calculate the number of clicks required for buttons $1$,$a$,$b$. Here is the plot of the result, where $x-$ and $y$-axis represent values of $a$ and $b$ respectively.

[image]

How to interpret the picture?

As a general algorithm to compute the number of clicks required to get to a fixed number $1\leq x\leq 100$, we can investigate linear combinations of $a$ and $b$: $$n\cdot a + m \cdot b,\;\; n,m\in \Bbb N_0.$$
We can calculate the least number of clicks by comparing results of $x-(na+mb)+n+m$which we may interpret as "click $n$ times $a$ and $m$ times $b$. For the remaining difference, click $1$ until we reach $x$ (note that this term is not necessarily minimized by the number $na+mb$ nearest to $x$, as $n+m$ may be too large).

**So as a heuristic, it is always good to have many different values of the form $na+mb$ and only small gaps between them, as adding $1$ is expensive.**

If $a$ and $b$ have a common divisor, all numbers of the form $na+mb$ will have that divisor too. So the number of "reachable numbers" is significantly higher, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

This is exactly what we can see in the picture: The "rays" of high average number of clicks represent pairs $(a,b)$ that share large divisors.

As the number of clicks does not change much if we increment $a$ or $b$ by $1$, which is satisfying as a heuristic argument, the average number of clicks is minimized for numbers which are "most coprime" in a sense that they have the highest distance to numbers sharing large divisors.

In the case of $1\leq x\leq 100$ the minimal average value of $5.21$ clicks is reached for $a=12$, $b=19$.

Comment: Ben, thank you so much for the wonderful response, and taking the time to explore the problem. I saw that initially you explained a connection to the Fibonnaci numbers, but this remark has been removed. Did you find it to be untrue, or was it removed for some other reason? Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, and thank you for sharing this interesting problem.

Comment: I do have one question about the graph. It seems to me like the maximal number of clicks would be with (1,1,1), but this doesn't seem to be reflected in the graph. Why is that?

Comment: @Doob Some numerical results for lower numbers suggested a connection and I found it reasonable on the first thought, as I saw Fibonacci appear in several places similar to this one. However, on the second thought I found that the distance between two consecutive Fibonacci numbers is unreasonable high for being optimal and numerical experiments confirmed my doubt For example, for $N=500$ I got optimal values for $14,61$. So I removed the conjecture immediately. I am sorry if that is disappointing to you.

Comment: @Doop concerning your second question, the graph reflects your claim: There are narrow regions near the $x-$ and $y-$ axis with very high average number of clicks, up to $50$. The regions are narrow because even for $(1,1,2)$ the average number is only half as high as for $(1,1,1)$. So the region around $(1,1,1)$ with high average values is rather small. Also, in the picture I believe the axis hides part of it. You would probably see more if we would only consider the range $1\leq a,b \leq 25$ as the lower right corner makes it harder to see differences in the upper left corner.

Comment: could you post the Python code ?